# Wired character in zsh

Tags: ubuntu, zsh

I have problem with **zsh** at command line for non English language
but after enter key the language show the right word, try on OSX have same issue too.

```
~   
❯ สว<0e31>สด<0e35>
สวัสดี
zsh: command not found: สวัสดี
```

i was check the locale everything is utf8

```
locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

and check if any fonts, it's have same problem.
i use **zsh** *version 5.0.2* and **oh-my-zh**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do `setopt combiningchars`.

> COMBINING_CHARS
>
> Assume that the terminal displays combining characters correctly. Specifically, if a base alphanumeric character is followed by one or more zero-width punctuation characters, assume that the zero-width characters will be displayed as modifications to the base character within the same width. Not all terminals handle this. If this option is not set, zero-width characters are displayed separately with special mark-up.
>
> -- [`zshoptions(1)` COMBINING_CHARS](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-COMBINING_005fCHARS)